# Generating State Machine using .Net framework dynamically

Tags: visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, workflow, workflow-foundation-4, state-machine

I am trying to model a given Problem using State Machine (.Net framework 4.0 update 1) and am wondering, if i can add new States to State machine in the run time?

I wanna model a street strukture as a State Machine. User will define his destinations on map which i want to use as states for the state machine.

Any help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a blog post by @RonJacobs where he created a prototype of a library that could do this a lot more straight forward - you might want to check that out.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rjacobs/archive/2011/06/08/creating-a-state-machine-in-code.aspx

Here is a blog post by him that is creating a workflow in code, the state machine wouldn't be much different, it would just leverage different accessors at the root.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rjacobs/archive/2011/06/22/authoring-activities-in-code-or-xaml.aspx

And here's yet another one that shows how you could load the workflows from the database.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rjacobs/archive/2011/06/15/how-to-load-wf4-workflow-services-from-a-database-with-iis-appfabric.aspx

Comment: i have some problems using the code could you help me with it?

Comment: @AsmaaEdress Sure, what's going on?

Comment: my problem is how to use the state machine? how can i use the code to define a workflow for some actions or triggers. I mean: i added a state 1 that visit another nonFinal state 2 when trigger 7 is fired. State 2 also visits state 3 (final state) if trigger 9 is fired. Then to run the machine, i fire the trigger 7 but how can i control the state machine and tell it to fire trigger 9? I don't know how to define an Entry action that fires trigger 9 by visiting State 2. Thanx 4 ur support

Answer (score 0):

If you want to edit your State Machine and then start new instances of it, no problem.  Add the states and transitions you want in code, and then use the new workflow definition to start new instances.

If you need to edit the definition of state machines that are already running, you'll need to use something like the Dynamic Update feature (in .NET 4.5, currently in Beta).

Comment: i actually dont know how to add a new State using code? All tutorials and exampels shows this using a GI. I will appreciate it, if u send me a link for that. All my States will be defined after Programm-Execution (dynamically in Run Time) so i need the code to write for example on maus click add the state named (x) to my state machine. Is that possible?